# Rotating a surface around an axis in 3D in javascript

Tags: javascript, 3d, rotation, three.js

I need to implement something and I'm not sure what to use (vanilla js vs library).

I want my user to visualize a 3d model building in its browser. Modelization is done in a modelization tool and then exported as a sequence of images to do a 360° degrees kind of thing. I'm using [this code](http://heartcode.robertpataki.com/360-image-slider/) to do the 360° thing and it works great.

In the modelization tool, the camera used to take pictures of the model (let's say it's a house as an example) is located a couple of meters high and rotating on a circle around the house. I can get those parameters (height and distance of the camera relative to the model center).

Now I also want "hot spots" on this 360 javascruot image spinner : user should be able to click on some surfaces (kitchen, dining, room1, room2, etc..) and get some data in a popup. [I've already done this in 2D with SVG](http://un-dimanche-a-la-campagne.fr/#plan-masse) and it's quite easy, but don't know how to do the same thing in this kind of 3D. I was thinking I could use a tool like three.js to do the job but don't know where to start - my math lessons are quite far away.

Ideally what I would like to do :

- draw a map of the "clickable" zones (SVG ?)
- rotate this map with the same angle than the one used in the first picture of the sequence (height / distance of the camera)
- when the user drags the 360 image spinner, compute the angle around x axis and rotate the map accordingly.

Does anyone have an idea how I could do so and what I should use ?

Thank you.

Comment: Check this js lib: http://famous.org/

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out. Sounds like a great lib at first glance. Did you use it ?

Comment: Not personally, but I've seen some magic done with it and talked to the people who wrote it. I wanna try it out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threejs can do the rotating+clickable area easily without asking you maths. You would just have to make the rotation the same period as your image slider.

- Its `SVGRenderer` may fit your project,
- But given the intensive CPU calculations the slider you linked ask, the `WebGLRenderer` may be the best solution since it uses the GPU for rendering, with very few to no programming difference (in threejs).
- If you go with the `WebGLRenderer` the more intuitive would be to get all in threejs. You would only have to load a texture and the geometry instead of a big set of images (you would gain seconds of loading time) and the result will get smoother due to twice less CPU computations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I first thought of using texture + geometry in three.js, but the model is too complex to be be reproduced in three.js and I want my images to be of high quality (hence the images spinner trick). I'll have a go with the WebGLRenderer so. What you be the best way to draw that "clickable map" of the rooms in three.js according to you ?

Comment: you can have a quick search of `ExtrudeGeometry` with threejs if you want the rooms to have some depth. If you just want them to be flat planes you would have to 'draw' them by passing vertices coordinates in a custom geometry for each room. In every case you have to end by coding a `raycaster` to check for mouseover/click events on the correct room. Just to warn, if you never coded in threejs, getting all that ready for production by yourself may take few days.

Comment: Never used three.js indeed :-) The idea is to have my house "cut" at wall's heightin my images, so user can see the inside of the house (no roof) and make a flat clickable shape on top of that with one geometry per room.

Comment: Ok. Many answers yet here on SO about threejs and ready to help if you have more in the next days :) Consider up/down voting + validating if the answer is correct

Comment: In the end, it wasn't that hard to do it with three.js. But I"m stuck with one last problem : I can't find a way to have the exact same scene configuration in 3Ds max (used to take the 360 pictures)  and three.js, thus resulting in differences when rotating the shapes over the images. I've set the following parameters the same : camera FOV / frustum, camera position, camera ratio. Is there anything else that could lead to differences in scene configuration ? I'll try to post a picture of my issue

Comment: Great. Yes pictures would help.

Comment: Hi - just to let you know, I just worked on this project again and in the end I was able to solve it using the right combination of FOV, focal length, camera position and ratio. I mixed all of those parameters in the first place. Thanks again for your help.